# WordPress тема Twenty Seventeen. Добавить виджеты в footer

Tags: css, wordpress

Как добавить еще два места для виджетов в footer, так чтобы они находились на одном этаже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы чего? Какие этажи? В вёрстке есть ряды (rows) и колонки (columns). Правильно ли я понимаю, что вам надо добавить колонок в подвал (footer)?

Comment: Вот на первой фото вы видете виджеты в футере, их два, я хочу, чтобы их было четыре в одном ряду. Использововал инструкцию надейнную в интернете, редактировал функцшионс пхп, стайл цсс и футер пхп,  добавились виджеты в настройках, но они становились во второй ряд. А мне надо, чтобы они были на одном ряду (этаже). Скорее всего вы правы, мне нужно еще две колонки в одном ряду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы еще не создали [дочернюю тему](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html), создайте ее. Все правки ниже слетят при обновлении основной темы twentyseventeen, если будут выполнены в основной теме.

**Сайдбары в консоли сайта**

Добавьте в `functions.php` дочерней темы следующий код. У вас на странице Внешний вид->Виджеты появятся два новых сайдбара - Footer 3 и Footer 4.

```
function widgets_init_771820() {
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Footer 3', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-4',
            'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your footer.', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Footer 4', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-5',
            'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your footer.', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</section>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'widgets_init_771820', 20, 0 );
```

**Вывод сайдбаров в подвале**

Создайте папку `wp-content/themes/дочерняя-тема/template-parts/footer`, а в ней файл `footer-widgets.php`. Вставьте в него следующий код (это модифицированный код файла `wp-content/themes/twentysenteen/template-parts/footer/footer-widgets.php`)

```
<?php
/**
 * Displays footer widgets if assigned
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

?>

<?php
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ||
     is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ||
     is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ) ||
     is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' ) ) :
    ?>

    <aside class="widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Footer', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?>">
        <?php
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="widget-column footer-widget-1">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="widget-column footer-widget-2">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="widget-column footer-widget-3">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="widget-column footer-widget-4">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </aside><!-- .widget-area -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

**Стилизация вывода**

Добавьте в `style.css` дочерней темы

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
    .site-footer .widget-column.footer-widget-1 {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .site-footer .widget-column.footer-widget-2 {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .site-footer .widget-column.footer-widget-3 {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .site-footer .widget-column.footer-widget-4 {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

Вот теперь все. Результат выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в style.css  дочерней темы внёс изменения которые написал. Файл футер виджет создал как и сказал,  и полностью заменил текст, на тот, что дал. В функшинс.пхп возникли проблемы, во-первых в дочерней теме его не было, я скопировал из основной, после этого появилась ошибка. Поэтому я удалил и просто внёс изменения в основном функшинс.пхп, который уже подтягивается к дочерней. Да появились как я и говорил выше виджеты, но не в одном ряду, а внизу. в три ряда, первый ряд - мои основные виджеты, ввторой ряд - третий виджет, третий ряд - четвертый виджет....

Comment: "Я скопировал из основной" - да что ж вы делаете. Почитайте, как надо создавать дочернюю тему. В ней изначально functions.php пустой

Comment: Делайте, как я написал. Создайте дочернюю, и по шагам. Я у себя на сайте все сделал в дочерней - test.kagg.eu - оттуда скриншот.

Comment: я сделал его пустым и просто внёс тот код, что вы дали - все равно ошибка в шапке сайта

Comment: у меня код с футера почему то в шапке сайта вместо логотипа

Comment: и не добавилось виджетов...... все сделал по инструкции, может код с функшионс не полный?

Comment: и кстати в инструкции нет ничего про создание пустого файла functions.php в папке дочерней темы.

Comment: Невнимательность, отсюда и ошибки. Сказано в инструкции "functions.php — дополняет functions.php родительской темы (загружается перед ним)." Где сказано, что туда что-то копировать надо? В начале файла functions.php вы поставили `<?php`  ??

Comment: У меня же все работает - зайдите на тестовый сайт. Ответ вам не из головы дан, все протестировано.

Comment: <?php поставил вначале файла, ошибка из шапки исчезла. Виджеты добавились, но опять же во втором и третьем ряду....

Comment: Неправильно что-то со стилями

Comment: Дайте ссылку на сайт

Comment: vogueclinic.my вот ссылка

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю, что не так? У вас 4 виджета в ряд, с 1 по 4

Comment: действительно, на другом компьютере в ряд. А на моём, такое же разрешение и такой же размер монитора, не в ряд.. чудеса. Спасибо в общем!

Comment: кеши, как есть. Ctrl+f5, или dev-tools -> Network -> Disable Cache